# html + javascript + socketio

Tags: javascript, python, flask, socket.io

I've some problem in sending a simple message trough socket.io:

giving a button in index.html:

```
<button id="button" onclick="functionTest()"> buttonTest </button>
```

and this function in my js :

```
function functionTest( function(event) {
     socket.emit('myevent', {data: "testval"});
     return false;
});
```

if I have a Flask server with:

```
@socketio.on('myevent', namespace='/test')
def test_message(message):
    print message
```

I should see in the Flask log, the message, but it doesn't work.
Where am I wrong?

thank you

Comment: Any errors in the browser or Python? Have you defined `socket` in the JS?

Comment: the socket is defined and opened, messages from server to client are ok, and there are no errors in the browser and in python

Comment: I changed the js code, defining a callback linked to the button click function and now it works. The html button contains only the id, and I use jquery in this way $("#buttonId").click(function(){ ... code with socket ....  }) and it works perfectly.